# Visual Studio 2015 is not completely loading my stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 is not completely loading my stylesheet so there are some elements missing when I test it. I'm not sure how to fix this issue. I'm new to Visual Studio so I'm not sure where the problem is. I've included my html & css files. Thank you

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Your ASP.NET application</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="home">
        <div id="header">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="styledimg"></div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="head-soc">
        <div id="linkedin-icon"><a href="http://linkedin.com/pub/titus-jackson/2/a2b/939">Linkedin</a></div>
        <div id="youtube-icon"><a href="http://youtube.com/titusishmael">Youtube</a></div>
        <div id="facebook-icon"><a href="http://facebook.com/titusjackson1">Facebook</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"><p>Create, Collaborate, Innovate</p></div>
    <div class="fadein">
        <img src="images/pic1.png" alt="" style="width: 90%; height: 825" class="active" />
        <img src="images/pic2.png" alt="" style="width: 90%; height: 825;" />
        <img src="images/pic3.png" alt="" style="width: 90%; height: 825;" />
        <img src="images/pic4.png" alt="" style="width: 90%; height: 825;" />
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="about">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h4>Titus Jackson</h4>
            <p>Film Maker ~ Screen Writer ~ Editor</p>
        </div>
        <img src="Images/Titus-Jackson1.jpg" alt="Titus Jackson" width="425" height="365" border="0" />
        <div id="section2">
            <p>
                For over 15 years <span>Cinemuze</span> has had the honor of working with some of the most talented creative collaborators Tulsa has to offer. We love working
                on a variety of projects. As it is our goal to be a well rounded company with our fingers in a lot of pies.
            </p>
            <p>
                Our paramount value is to approuch the material with excellence and an orignal point of view to tell a unique and compelling story. It is our belief that
                life is what you make of it, and the saddest lost is not to explore all your potential in the short time you've been given.
            </p>
            <p>
                We've had the opportunity to work on multiple feature films and national television shows ranging from christian television to TLC television. We've created
                mulitple award winning music videos, short films and evevn a feature film. Feel free to take a look around the site, drop us an email, we look forward to hearing
                from you.
            </p>
            <a href="mailto:titusjackson@mac.com"><img src="images/email1.png" alt="email1" width="26" height="26" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="projects">
        <h5>View our current projects</h5>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <iframe width="265" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8CZJzUk7fFM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <p>Eugene Gregory Promo</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <iframe width="265" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cLm3Vh4_Ruc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <p>Family Cup Promo</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <iframe width="265" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2t9-vVNgF7c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <p>This Generation</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
        <section3>
            <h3>To connect with us:</h3>
            <p><span>Cinemuze</span> is based in Tulsa, Oklahoma and travels widely for a variety of projects.</p>
            <p>If your interested in our work, you can connect with us via email or phone.</p>
        </section3>
        <div class="section4">
            <img src="images/email1.png" alt="email" width="26" height="26" />
            <a href="mailto:titusjackson@mac.com">
                <p>titusjackson@mac.com</p>
            </a>
            <img src="images/phone.png" alt="phone" width="24" height="24" />
            <p>+1 (918) 671-3340</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
            setInterval(function() {
                $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(2000)
                .next('img').fadeIn(2000)
                .end().appendTo('.fadein');},
                3000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #42413C;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}


#header {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -15px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(60,59,59,1.00);
    transition-duration: 1s;    
    z-index: 25;
}

div#header nav {
    width: 1425;
    height: 110px;
}

div#header ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 100px;
    float: left;
}

div#header li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 64px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

div#header a {
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     line-height: 45px;
     font-size: .9em;
     text-transform: capitalize;
}

div#header a:hover {
    color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
}

div#styledimg {
    background-image: url(images/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 224px;
    height: 85px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}


/*page-specific header styles*/

#header {
    background-color: rgba(60,59,59,1.00);
    width: 1425;
    height: 110px;
}

/* layout styles*/

/*home page*/

div#home {
    height: 950px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.fadein {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 825px;  
}

.fadein img {
    border: 80px solid rgba(60,59,59,1.00);
    height: 825;
    position: absolute;
    left: -225px;
    top: -35px;
    z-index: -9;
}

#header {
    background-color: rgba(60,59,59,1.00);
}

#head-soc {
    width: 129;
    height: 86;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 300px;
    right: 25px;
    position: fixed;    
    z-index: 25;
}

#head-soc a {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

 #linkedin-icon a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 43px;
    width: 43px;
    border: 0;
    background-image: url(Images/socialsprites_white.png); 
    display: block;
    float: right;   
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
#linkedin-icon a:hover {
    background-image: url(Images/socialsprites_white.png); 
    background-position: 0px -43px;
}

#youtube-icon a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 43px;
    width: 43px;
    border: 0;
    background-image: url(Images/socialsprites_white.png); 
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-position: -43px 0px;
}

 #youtube-icon a:hover {
    background-image: url(Images/socialsprites_white.png); 
    background-position: -43px -43px;
}

 #facebook-icon a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 43px;
    width: 43px;
    border: 0;
    background-image: url(Images/socialsprites_white.png);
    display: block;
    float: right;
    background-position: -86px -85px;
}

 #facebook-icon a:hover {
    background-image: url(Images/socialsprites_white.png);
    background-position: -86px -128px;
}

.content p {
    font-family: BlairMdITC TT-Medium;
    font-size: 44px;
    width: 550px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15%;
    margin-top: 25%;
    color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
    position: absolute;
}

/* about page*/

div#about {
     background-color:rgba(188,184,184,1.00);
     height: 550px;
     margin-top: -5px;
     padding-top: 100px;
     z-index: 35;
 }

.wrapper h4 {
    font-famiy: Geneva;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-left: 224px;
    color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.wrapper p {
    font-family: Geneva;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 226px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: rgba(134,133,133,1.00);
}

h6 {
    padding-left: 225px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: rgba(60,59,59,1.00);
}
img {
     float: left;
     margin-left: 225px;
     margin-right: 15px;
 }

#section2 {
     font-family: Helvetica;
     font-size: 16px;
     color: rgba(60,59,59,1.00);
     width: 1280px;
     padding-top: -80px;
     height: 300px;
 }

 #section2 p {
     color: rgba(60,59,59,1.00);
 }

#section2 img {
    margin-left: 2px;   
}

span {
     color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
 }


 /* projects page */

 div#projects {
     background-color: #3A3939;
     background-position: 25px;
     height: 450px;
     margin: 0px; 
     line-height: 0;
     padding-top: 25px; 

 }

 div#projects ul {
     list-style: none;
     margin-left: 100px;
     float: left;
 }


 div#projects li {
     float: left;
     margin-top: 65px;
     margin-left: 120px;
 }

 div#projects li p {
     margin-left: 20px;
     text-align: center;    
     font-family: BlairMdITC TT-Medium;
     font-size: 20px;
     color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00)
 }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 632px) {
     div#projects li {
         float: none;
         margin-top: 65px;
         margin-left: 95px;
     }

     div#projects li p {
         margin-left: 10px;
         text-align: center;
     }

 }
  div#projects h5 {
    margin-left: 650px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:rgba(179,178,178,1.00);
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
 }

 p {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 195px;
    color: rgba(249,247,247,1.00);
 }

 /* contact page */

 div#contact {
     background-image:url(images/studio4.png);
     background-size: cover;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     padding-top: 35px;
     padding-bottom: 100px; 
 }

 section3 h3 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
    margin-left: 660px;
    margin-top: 75px;
 }

 section3 p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    width: 650px;
    padding-left: 85px;
    margin-left: 385px;
 }

 .section4 {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    margin-left: 440px;
    margin-top: 50px;
 }

 .section4 a {
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 .section4 a p:hover {
     color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
}




/* ~~ The footer ~~ */




/*HTML 5 support - Sets new HTML 5 tags to display:block so browsers know how to render the tags properly. */
header, section, footer, aside, article, figure {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: check if the stylesheetfile is included in the project

Answer (score 0):

So the style sheet shows up, it's just the images referenced in your style sheet that aren't showing? When I've had that problem, it's either an incorrect filepath or the content files haven't actually been added to the project. If you right click on your images folder and click "Add > Existing Item" for all your images, that fixes the problem (for me at least) sometimes.

Comment: my slideshow images show up but they are not in the right place and my social sprites show in my design view but do not show when I test it. I have checked all my links.

Comment: I have found the answer to my problem. Thank you!